# Teamcity + Octopus and umbraco packages

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, umbraco, umbraco7, octopus-deploy

Currently we are deploying our Umbraco site with teamcity and octopus deploy, having uSync installed to synchronize datatypes, document types etc. between enviroments.

Now im facing our first problem with our CI setup: How do i automatically install/uninstall any installed umbraco packages? If i install a package through the Umbraco interface, locally, and then deploy to our test environment, then i get an error until i install the package manually. This I have to do every time I deploy.

What is the correct way of managing/synchronizing packages between environments when using CI?

Comment: ```Nuget restore``` before you build the application on TeamCity. That will restore your installed packages that you have in packages.config (not sure if it's that particular file). Make sure uSync doesn't mess up your process. Keep uSync to exporting/importing manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to either:

**1. Install all packages via Nuget**

If you install all packages via. Nuget, then teamcity will take care of everything for you when building the solution.

**2. Reference the package .dll**

If the package is not available as a Nuget package, then download if via Umbraco, find the .dll and move it to another folder in your solution and reference the .dll from there instead.